# How can i find and change the background color of header and footer coming from pancakeswap/uikit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, exchange-server, styled-components, decentralized-applications

I fork the DexoExchange from GitHub. Now I want to customize it according to myself. But I'm facing an issue.The issue is I cannot find the header and footer tag in this project.Pancakeswap/uikit is used in it which is new to me and some tags are coming from it. my only need is to change the background color of Header and Footer

Here is the link of my git repo: https://github.com/sohaib57/dexoExchange.git

Actual picture:

[image]

myproject:

[image]